# TinyMCE wasn't loaded in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm currently using TinyMCE as my primary text editior in my website, but now I'm facing a quite tricky problem that I embeded TinyMCE in a html file A, and I used JQuery to load file A into another html file B's div element, and everything worked fine except the TinyMCE in file A was not loaded.

Anyone here encountered similar problem b4?

Comment: I think you'll need to post some relevant code from A and B atleast. I think it a possible fix is to use the `.live()` function - http://api.jquery.com/live/ but depending on which version you are using this is deprecated and it looks like you should use `.on()` instead.

Comment: So putting the pieces together, what does the served HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to initialise your TinyMCE editor after it has been added to page A, by adding the following code after your `load('fileB.html')`:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'simple',
    language: 'en'
});
```

You can obviously amend those settings as required. [Full reference](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code, after loading the file, you might want to call the

```
tinyMCE.init({
  // ...
});
```

You would place this part from file 'A' in a function and call that function after loading the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call eighter the tinymce init function like JScoobyCed already stated or you just call this

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'id_of_your_textarea');
```